# how to solve the error of invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null ()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I started testing the react native application with jest I started testing the `App.js` file and found "dependency" errors with node modules. But one of the mistakes I can't solve is this one.

[image]

I don't understand the error and I don't know how to solve it

`__tests__/App.js`

```
import 'react-native'
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import App from '../App';


describe('Some component', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.mock('@react-native-community/async-storage');

  });

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
        <App/>
    ).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

`package.json`

```
...    
"jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "cacheDirectory": "./cache",
        "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
          "./app/utils/vendor"
        ],
        "coverageThreshold": {
          "global": {
            "statements": 80
          }
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "/node_modules/(?!react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|react-navigation|native-base-shoutem-theme|native-base|lodash|static-container|@react-navigation|react-native-rfid-nfc-scanner)"
        ],
        "setupFiles": [
          "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
        ]
      },
...
```

Comment: [Look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53879892/3930220)